# Using an attribute selector with adjacent sibling

Tags: css

I’m trying to use an attribute selector with adjacent classes.
However it doesn't seem to work together.

Are there any other ways to get adjacent, non identical sibling to apply css?

I’ve also tried this, with no luck:

```
.tbslant-uphill + .tbslant-downhill {margin-top: -120px;}
```

```
[class^="tbslant"] + [class^="tbslant"] {margin-top: -120px;}
```

```
<section class="content-block bg-green slant-on tbslant-uphill"></div>
<section class="content-block bg-green slant-on tbslant-downhill”></div>
```

Comment: This is not a problem with the adjacent sibling combinator, but that `[class^="tbslant"]` does not select either of those elements to begin with. `^=` means “the value _starts with_” - but the content of the class attribute of your elements _does not_ start with `tbslant`.

Comment: The first one however works fine - once you correct your faulty HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attribute selector requires that the "tbslant" is at the **start** of the list of class names and in your case it's not.

You need the selector for "tbslant" appearing **anywhere** in the list.

```
[class*="tbslant"] + [class*="tbslant"]
```

```css
[class*="tbslant"] + [class*="tbslant"] {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: blue;
}

section {
  padding: 1em;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="content-block bg-green slant-on tbslant-uphill"></section>

<section class="content-block bg-green slant-on tbslant-uphill"></section>
```